# MIPS loops/array

Tags: arrays, loops, mips

I've been given the pseudocode for what I wanted to create in MIPS, basically to increment array values using a loop. I need to start the loop by initialising $s0 to hold the base address of the array and $s1 to hold to index of the array. The index should be zero-based, meaning the tenth element would have a zero-based array index of 9.

If anyone could help me and explain the MIPS code that would help a lot.

- (label) start loop
- load the given word
- if the word doesnt equal zero:  increment the index
- add 2 to the word
- store it
- (jump to label) start loop

with an else type condition to drop off the bottom.
I've also been given a data segment which defines 10 values which are stored next to one another as words in memory. Shown here:

```
.data #by default, the "data segment" starts at address 0x10010000
.word 1
.word 2
.word 3
.word 4
.word 5
.word 6
.word 7
.word 8
.word 9
.word 0

.text #instructions start below
```

Also, I have the Permit Extended Pseudo Unchecked.

I have currently tried the code below:

```
.data

array: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0

.text

main:

la   $s0 array
move $s1 $zero

loop:


    sll $t0 $s1 2
    add $t1 $s0 $t0
    lw  $t2 0($t1)

    beq $t2 $zero exit

    addi $s1 $s1 1


    addi $t2 $t2 2
    sw   $t2 0($t1)

    j loop

exit:

    jr $ra
```

It works fine when extended permitted pseudo is checked, but not when unchecked, as I need it to work when unchecked.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I can't see any code except for some directives for declaring an array of words. StackOverflow is not an appropriate site for learning MIPS assembly; use a textbook or some online tutorials for that. Ask a question if you've run into a problem with some code that you've written where you've already tried to diagnose the problem yourself first.

Comment: .data

array: .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0

.text

main:

    la   $s0 array
    move $s1 $zero

    loop:

        
        sll $t0 $s1 2
        add $t1 $s0 $t0
        lw  $t2 0($t1)

        beq $t2 $zero exit

        addi $s1 $s1 1

       
        addi $t2 $t2 2
        sw   $t2 0($t1)

        j loop

    exit:

        jr $ra

Comment: That code should be part of your question, not a comment. You should also explain (in your question) in what way the code isn't behaving the way you expected it to.

Comment: I have used the above code upto now, it works fine when I have Permit Extended Pseudo Checked but no when unchecked, but I need it to work when unchecked....

Comment: Ok, so the problem is your use of pseudo instructions. That was completely unobvious in your original question. If you google for "mips pseudo instructions" you will find information about the pseudo instructions and which real instructions they correspond to.